# all subsets borel

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology

Assume Martin's axiom plus $\neg CH$. It is well known, via almost disjoint forcing,  that every set of reals of size less than continuum is an example of a metric space whose subsets are all relatively $F_{\sigma}$ and hence Borel. Now suppose (along with $MA + \neg CH$) that every subset of a metric space $X$ is Borel. Must every subset of $X$ be $F_{\sigma}$?

Comment: Without MA + not CH, it is consistent that there is a set of reals $X$ such that every subset of $X$ is relatively Borel, but not every subset is relatively $F_\sigma$.  This is due to Arnie Miller.  But I guess this is not what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Answer copied from the comments:

Without MA + not CH, it is consistent that there is a set of reals $X$ such that every subset of $X$ is relatively Borel, but not every subset is relatively $F_\sigma$. This is due to Arnie Miller. – Paul McKenney